# Dynamic query with string value

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm using ScottGu's Dynamic Linq and everything work fine, but I've an issue:

There are some tables which contains a primay key as string type, so how can I make a dynamic query passi string type to where calusole?

I cannot find any syntax for that...

Example:
`QueryAbleObject.Where(StringField = 'someValue');` -> It throws a parser exception..

Comment: Ops..Excuse me, I just found the exact syntaxt..Simply passing " character instead of single quot.

Comment: Exactly, since the query is in C# it should use C# syntax, not SQL. Submit an answer to your question so it can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Excerpt from OP's comment above:*

> "I just found the exact syntaxt..Simply passing " character instead of single quot."